# Alarm Manger is not triggering broadcast receiver exactly at Specified Time

Tags: android, android-pendingintent, android-alarms, android-broadcast

**Requirement :**  I want to **trigger alarm  and  execute broadcast receiver every 3 minutes exactly**,But alarm is not triggering exactly every 3 minutes,here is my code,Any help??

**Alarm Manager**

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent in = new Intent(this,GPSReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pi =  PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,234324243, in, 0);

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(new Date());
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 3*60*1000, pi);
Log.i("hei",new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S").format(cal.getTimeInMillis()));
```

**BroadCast Receiver**

```
public class GPSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.i("hei","GPSReceiver Called");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
       }
}
```

**According to above code,alarm is triggered in below order(But not always in same order, as i mentioned below)**

07-19 14:11:53.194: I/hei(30310):   **2014-07-19 14:11:53.202**

07-19 14:11:53.194: I/hei(30310):   GPSReceiver Called

07-19 14:12:03.061: I/hei(30310):   **2014-07-19 14:12:03.68**

07-19 14:12:03.061: I/hei(30310):   GPSReceiver Called

07-19 14:14:53.186: I/hei(30310):   **2014-07-19 14:14:53.194**

07-19 14:14:53.186: I/hei(30310):   GPSReceiver Called

07-19 14:15:03.030: I/hei(30310):   **2014-07-19 14:15:03.36**

07-19 14:15:03.030: I/hei(30310):   GPSReceiver Called

07-19 14:17:53.186: I/hei(30310):   **2014-07-19 14:17:53.193**

07-19 14:17:53.186: I/hei(30310):   GPSReceiver Called

07-19 14:18:03.030: I/hei(30310):   **2014-07-19 14:18:03.38**

07-19 14:18:03.030: I/hei(30310):   GPSReceiver Called